# String contents not being changed

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is my main view where I create an object of getDepthData() that holds a string variable that I want to update when the user click the button below. But it never gets changed after clicking the button

```
import SwiftUI

struct InDepthView: View {
    @State var showList = false
    @State var pickerSelectedItem = 1
    @ObservedObject var data = getDepthData()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) { 
                Button(action: {
                    self.data.whichCountry = "usa"
                    print(" indepthview "+self.data.whichCountry)
                }) {
                Text("change value")
                }
         }
     }
}
```

Here is my class where I hold a string variable to keep track of the country they are viewing. But when every I try to modify the whichCountry variable it doesn't get changed

```
class getDepthData: ObservableObject {

    @Published var data : Specific!
    @Published var countries : HistoricalSpecific!
    @State var whichCountry: String = "italy"

    init() {
        updateData()
    }

    func updateData() {

        let url = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/"

        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url+"\(self.whichCountry)")!) { (data, _, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            let json = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Specific.self, from: data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = json
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `whichCountry` variable as `@Published` to apply changes on it

```swift
@Published var whichCountry: String = "italy"
```

Comment: its not liking the way im calling it in indepthView() any reason for that?

Comment: `@State` is great for simple properties that belong to a specific view and never get used outside that view, in your case you have a model and it should be an observable object to manage the change states between view and the model

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark `whichCountry` as a `@Published` variable so SwiftUI publishes a event when this property have been changed. This causes the body property to reload

`@Published var whichCountry: String = "italy"`

By the way it is a convention to write the first letter of your class capitalized:

`class GetDepthData: ObservableObject { }`

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, you need to define the whichCountry variable as @Published to apply changes to it. In addition you probably want to update your data because whichCountry has changed. So try this:

```
@Published var whichCountry: String = "italy" {
    didSet {
        self.updateData()
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! and love  the  addition  of didset  exactly what i needed